# In R, how can I fill color the map with dataset(csv file) using ggplot or other things?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I want to make the map like below picture. This picture shows the source of high frequency in each country.
[image]

For doing this, I prepare a 'csv' file including "longitude", "latitude" and "source" like below, which is a sample of population. There are many source in each latitude and longitude, which is corresponding to each country. For example, First row is referring to "UK" in "map.where function".

```
latitude    longitude   source
51.318488   -1.0605415  English
51.4603395  -0.115406   Korean
47.9818605  0.195548    English
40.226213   28.954341   English
53.717188   27.978099   English
45.800371   9.0838175   French
41.292651   12.573501   French
41.8984165  12.5451455  Japanese
53.651504   -2.6340755  English
48.382929   31.181446   Korean
40.176071   29.121293   English
51.6471965  -0.7084465  English
40.54108    -3.63148    English
40.6280185  -8.6396565  French
51.5424365  -0.159403   French
36.89007    30.680889   Japanese
48.8588335  2.347003    English
52.238854   -0.882951   Korean
37.383198   -5.923545   English
45.080766   11.5820475  English
41.392657   2.1412275   English
41.0213205  29.0052225  French
53.0184905  -1.356315   French
```

Using this data, now I could do until below code. But, it could show only the point of source. I don't have idea of how could I fill color.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)

my_data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
head(my_data)

longitude = my_data$longitude
latitude = my_data$latitude
source = my_data$source
df = data.frame(source, longitude, latitude)

register_google(key="I am using my own google API key")

map <- get_map(location = 'Europe', zoom = 4)
map <- ggmap(map)

map + geom_point(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, colour = source), df, alpha = 0.3)
```

How can I do make the above first picture?

Comment: have you tried `scale_colour_manual`? can you add your current output as I can't quite understand... you might need to use `fill` not `colour`

Comment: In the first map, each country is filled with a color. As far as I can see, you have data points in your data. You can surely draw points on a map. But you cannot fill in polygons with the data. If you want to fill in polygons, search for SO questions or blogs. I am sure you can find many examples.